# Network Speed Limit

Tags: networking, tcpip, performance

I have a nic "Local Network" and I would like to limit throughput speed for it to 1480kb/s and 208kb/s upload

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in fact talking about a Windows machine, there are several ways this can be done:

1.) Change TCP settings on the device in question. This will lower the effective bandwidth, but isn't terribly elegant.

2.) Purchase some rate limiting software such as NetLimiter. It's $30 for one license, but it should do what you're asking.

http://www.netlimiter.com/

3.) Limit bandwidth used by that particular host from the gateway, if you have a gateway supporting rate limiting. TC is great if you're using Linux, and Microsoft ISA has similar features.

For more information about these options, read here: http://www.ezlan.net/monitor.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this shell script:

http://www.topwebhosts.org/tools/traffic-control.php

Comment: Based off the "Local Network" comment of his, I assume he's talking about a Windows machine.

Comment: Yes I am. *dubby text cause of limit*

Comment: color me stupid for assuming.